# How to attach png files to qwtplot

Tags: qt, qwt

Is it possible to use png files in QwtPlot? Normally i can use svg files in my plots with QwtPlotSvgitem class but i could not succeed with these png files. Please give me a clue about that.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are several ways to do this. You don't specify what kind of image you want to draw (and where).

You might create a `QwtPlotMarker` ([Qwt docs](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_marker.html)) with a custom `QwtSymbol` ([Qwt docs](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_symbol.html)). You can try `QwtSymbol::setPixmap()`. A `QPixmap` can be created by calling its constructor with the file name of the *.png image ([Qt docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html)).